# iPhone getting ABC Forbids explicit message sent of auto release

Tags: iphone

I'm copying some code from one project to another to fill in a table View,
I'm getting this error

```
ABC Forbids explicit message sent of auto release
```

when I'm trying to create a  UITableViewCell object.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       // this line produces the error
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: HAHA. Did you mean ARC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant ARC (not ABC)?  When your project is using Automatic Reference Counting, you're not meant to call `release`, `retain`, or `autorelease`.  In this case you can just get rid of the autorelease call and your code should compile.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using ARC (or ABC :D) u should just `release` it normally in the `-(void)delloc`
And if you using delete the line of code (just the `autorelease`).

Comment: In non-ARC code a release would still be necessary in this method!